# Can trigonometric equations be graphed?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, systems-of-equations

I was solving various trigonometric equations. I was confused that how are they solved easily by using methods that are useful to solve algebraic equations. Do the trigonometric functions in trigonometric equations are variables? If they are not then how am I finding the roots using a system? And if yes, then there must be a corresponding graph of every equation, trigonometric equation.

Comment: The following  sentence is unclear:  "Do the trigonometric functions in trigonometric equations are variables?"

Comment: You are allowed to compose functions whenever it makes sense. For example, if $f(x)=1-x^2,$ you can write $f(\sin(t))=1-\sin^2(t).$ This expression makes sense for all $t$. Now, if we need to solve $1-x^2=0,$ you know how to by factoring, namely $1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x),$ and therefore $f(x)=0$ when $x=\pm 1.$ But this is an extremely abstract expression, it works for ANY real $x,$ including $\sin(t)$ for any real $t.$ Therefore you can solve $0=f(\sin(t))=1-\sin^2(t)$ by factoring $(1-\sin(t))(1+\sin(t))$ and solving $\sin(t)=\pm 1.$

Comment: No, the variables are the arguments of the trigonometric functions. In $\tan^3(\sqrt x)-\sin(x^2)=3$, there is one variable $x$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You should read Section 1.5 of the book A=B. There is a sense in which the OP's statement makes sense, and is a very important and useful observation.

Comment: @Nathanson. Could you tell me which book ? After commenting, I started thinking (more) and this question does very deep as you say. Thanks :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The book is called "A=B" that is the title. It is by Petkovsek, Wilf, and Zeilberger. They have it [for free here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html).

Comment: @ Philosopher, There is a very useful idea that goes along the line you are saying. Assume that you have a trigonometric equation, or identity such that you can write all the appearances of trigonometric functions in terms of say $\cos(x)$. Not all equations satisfy this condition, but equations like these appear in practice and in class more than often. Then you can replace $\cos(x)$ by a variable say $y$ and obtain an equivalent non-trigonometric equation (sometimes even rational).  The process of solution becomes algorithmic after that.

Comment: An alternative for doing the same thing is to write all appearances of trigonometric functions in terms of $e^{ix}$. The same idea applies if one can do so.  It is probably a matter of taste but I often find this one more comfortable to use. Example: Suppose we want to prove that $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$. We re-write this as $\frac{e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix}}{2}=(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2})^2-(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i})^2$. Replace $e^{ix}$ by $y$ and we just need to check the equation $\frac{y^2+y^{-2}}{2}=(\frac{y+y^{-1}}{2})^2-(\frac{y-y^{-1}}{2i})^2$ between rational functions.